# Primefaces datatable dynamic object[]

Tags: jsf, object, dynamic, primefaces, datatable

I want to create a dynamic Primefaces datatable from the result of an sql query that gives me a `List<Object[]>` as result. The corresponding column names are stored in a `List<String>`.

The columns and the length of the `Object[]` field should be dynamic.

How to deal with the `List<Object[]>` in the Datatable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `<p:columns>`. See also [PrimeFaces `<p:dataTable>` showcase - dymamic columns](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/columns.xhtml).

Provided that you actually mean that you've the `data` in a `List<Object[]>` and the `columnNames` in the same order in `List<String>`, then this should do:

```
<p:dataTable value="#{bean.data}" var="item">
    <p:columns value="#{bean.columnNames}" var="columnName" columnIndexVar="i">
        <f:facet name="header">#{columnName}</f:facet>
        #{item[i]}
    </p:columns>
</p:dataTable>
```

Comment: trying this throws the following exception: com.google.common.collect.ComputationException: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: FormBeanCall and FormBeanCall$ColumnModel disagree on InnerClasses attribute. I think its because he wants a ColumnModel Object and not a List<String> for columns value!

Comment: Your classpath is dirty. Clean, rebuild, redeploy, restart.